# expressions in C#'s using statement

Tags: c#, expression, using-statement

The C# reference manual defines the syntax of *using* statements as:

```
using-statement:
   using   (    resource-acquisition   )    embedded-statement

resource-acquisition:
   local-variable-declaration
   expression
```

Can someone provide me with an example that uses an expression inside *using* statement. 
Conventional examples are using a variable declaration.

Comment: `var res = GetResource(); using (res) { ... }` This style is not recommended because `res` is still in scope after the `using` block, but has been disposed.

Comment: So, only an identifier? To me the grammar looks very permissive, and it looks like at the syntactic level all expressions are allowed.

Comment: @Ali: "only an identifier?" --- it's an expression, as you asked.

Comment: Sure, it is! I was wondering if there is any more complex, say conditional expressions, is allowed.

Comment: Yes, they are. Any *expression* is allowed. I was just providing one example. You could as well `using (GetResource())` or `using (flag ? resA : resB)` etc.

Answer (score 3):

An example of using an expression is as follows:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();

using(stream)
{
    //Perform operations with stream here.
}

//Stream is now disposed.
```

Here, the `stream` variable is declared outside the using, but wrapped by the using.  It will then dispose the `stream` variable upon completion.

This isn't a very common pattern, but it is useful for where you may need to perform other operations on the resource after it has been disposed of.

This can be used with method calls, etc.  Essentially any expression that evaluates to a type of `IDisposable` can be used.  Generally, not having access to the `IDisposable` inside the using statement isn't that useful.

The only scenario where I have seen it used this way is in ASP.NET MVC with the form helpers such as.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("Name");
}
```

Comment: this is totally wrong, as in [.net docs(third part after remark header)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement#remarks) they explicitly mentions that you must declare your IDisposable variable in the using block not before it

Comment: Reading the documentation you linked I see, "You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this isn't a best practice. In this case, after control leaves the using block, the object remains in scope but probably has no access to its unmanaged resources."

Which supports the usage pattern I outlined above. It's not best practice, but the answer is also not "totally wrong."

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
//Create the file. 
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    AddText(fs, "This is some text");
    AddText(fs, "This is some more text,");
    AddText(fs, "\r\nand this is on a new line");
    AddText(fs, "\r\n\r\nThe following is a subset of characters:\r\n");

    for (int i=1;i < 120;i++)
    {
        AddText(fs, Convert.ToChar(i).ToString());

    }
}
```

Explanation:

Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object at the and of the block.

It will call the Dispose method even if an Exception is thrown.

Comment: this is an example of `local-variable-declaration` not `expression`

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to look at is actually the definition of `local-variable-declaration` from section 8.5.1

> A local-variable-declaration declares one or
>   more local variables.
>   
>   local-variable-declaration:
>  local-variable-type
>     local-variable-declarators
>   
>   local-variable-type:
>  type
>  var
>   
>   local-variable-declarators:
>   local-variable-declarator
>  local-variable-declarators   ,   local-variable-declarator
>   
>   local-variable-declarator:
>  identifier
>   identifier   =   local-variable-initializer
>   
>   local-variable-initializer:
>  expression
>  array-initializer

So a `local-variable-declaration` could be expressed as `type identifer = expression`. So what the specification for `using` is telling you is you can either declare a variable in the form `var variableName = xxxxxxx` or you can just use the `xxxxxx` part by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Another example of `expression` that I don't see mentioned here is:

```
IDisposable disposable;
using (disposable = new SomeDisposableObject()) {
   // do something
}
```

or

```
IDisposable disposable;
using (disposable = SomeExpressionOrFunctionThatEvaluatesToADisposable()) {
   // do something
}
```

The reference doesn't have to be of type `IDisposable`, it could be any type that implements it.